# In a Mobile Website if a Javascript can enhance UX but will make the page little slower to load, is it ok to do that?

Tags: mobile, javascript, mobile-web, performance

In a Mobile Website if a JavaScript can enhance UX but will make the page little slower to load, is it ok to use javascript?

Or we should always give preference to speed specially on mobile?

Comment: Is it possible for you to instead progressively enhance the website, i.e., load the basic site (for quick rendition) and subsequently load additional JavaScript etc. used to enhance the UX?

Comment: @jensgram - you mean Loading page data before and javascript after? by keeping javascript file at bottom of the page?

Comment: Yes, that's one way to do it. See [Vinko Vrsalovic's answer](http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/10997/in-a-mobile-website-if-a-javascript-can-enhance-ux-but-will-make-the-page-little/10999#10999).

Answer (score 1):

Of course, it depends on what exactly are you enhancing and at what cost. But the ideal solution would be to load fast a minimally usable version and enhance it progressively, for example via [loading Javascript on demand](http://javascript-reference.info/speed-up-your-javascript-load-time.htm)

Answer (score 0):

Kind of impossible to say. You have to weight the advantages that the javascript gives the user to the added size of the total page. In general though - javascript is light weight and can be used to partially load data with AJAX - which in the end will make the total experience load faster.

Answer (score 0):

You can also combine @vinko-vrsalovic answer with [Application Cache](http://html5doctor.com/go-offline-with-application-cache/)
That way the file is only loaded at the beginning and when you update it.